# Google analytics error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

i have problem with google analytics.

i have code in my website : https://www.poma.sk/  code is here : https://prnt.sc/saaix8

but i see error in console : https://prnt.sc/saah3d

what is wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an ad blocker preventing the Google Tag Manager code from loading. In my case, I had to allow the domain in my Pi-hole admin settings.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this row:

```
<script async src="https://www.1a3c9a8ebcc58dac607cdcc47329d03d-gdprlock/gtag/js?id=UA-61560074-2"></script>
```

Should be as below::

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-61560074-2">
```

Answer (score -1):

Michele .

Code which I add to site is :

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-61560074-2"></script>
<script> 
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-61560074-2');
gtag ("config", "AW-804674955");
</script>
```

Why it change in site ?

Comment: Hi, i solved this problem. Extension GDPR for Joomla blocked this script. 
many thanks